# Gtkwebkit, save html to pdf

Tags: gtk, pdf-generation

Last days I search for best and shortest way to convert html files to pdf. Since I create my html files with C program and see them through gtkwebkit which uses cairo it should be some efficient and direct way to convert content of showed page to html with C (I think).
But can't find any example or direction to go on the net.

Until now, among different virtual printers, I find only commandline tools which are maded in perl or which depends on qt what is not wanted.

Please for any suggestion, example or advice to get this functionality from gtkwebkit and if not, maybe something with some tiny C library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can tell from reading the documentation (haven't tried it out myself):

1. Get the main frame with [`webkit_web_view_get_main_frame()`](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-webkitwebview.html#webkit-web-view-get-main-frame).
2. Create a [`GtkPrintOperation`](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/gtk-High-level-Printing-API.html) with `gtk_print_operation_new()`.
3. Set the `export-file` property on your print operation to be the name of the PDF you want to export to.
4. Print the frame with [`webkit_web_frame_print_full()`](http://webkitgtk.org/reference/webkitgtk/stable/webkitgtk-WebKitWebFrame.html#webkit-web-frame-print-full). Make sure to pass `GTK_PRINT_OPERATION_ACTION_EXPORT` as the 'action' parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much ptomato. Yes, you're right. Here is no need any additional software. Generic "gtk printing" do the job. I tryed now and it is max simple and fast! gtk_print_operation_set_export_filename(operation, "/home/name/proba.pdf"); this is solution!

Comment: Hi ptomato, i am looking for the code to convert html to pdf. If by chance can u share with me.

Thanks for the advance.

Comment: @Mohanraj I don't have that code. The above answer describes how to write it yourself.

Comment: @ptomato, Thanks for the reply. I did the part to cnvert html to pdf, but the thing is, i want to convert it without opening the gtk main window.

Answer (score 0):

I once wrote some code, to accomplish that without opening a window. But then I ran into a problem with using that code from multiple threads (in a webserver e.g.). I made some research and I figured out that gtk itself is single threaded. So I made my code thread safe, by queuing the print operations to the main thread. Anyway, if it helps, check it out... https://github.com/gnudles/wkgtkprinter